# How to create QR code in Axapta 2009

Tags: qr-code, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I need to genrate QR code for an item in Dynamic AX 2009.

Is there any functionality in AX 2009 to do so?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ramanan M provided a video showing [how to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOj3OTBra_g)!
It should work in AX 2009 as well.

You will have to integrate with an external component.